# How to find Wronskian of this ordinary differential equation problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, wronskian

[image]

I know how to find the Wronskian if solutions are available. And if I can solve the problem.

I don't know how to solve this problem.

Is there a way to find the Wronskian of this problem without actually using the solution process used in variable coefficients?

I am just interested in the Wronskian.  I have just tried so far substitutions which lead no where.

Comment: See below answered by deiter enns

Comment: The Wronskian (note spelling) does actually depend on the choice of solutions.  However the exercise in your image gives values for the two solutions you are supposed to use at $x=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $w=w(y_1,y_2)(t)$ a the Wronskian of $y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y=0$, then
$$
w'=(y_1y_2'-y_1'y_2)'=y_1y_2''-y_1''y_2=y_1(-py_2'-qy_2)-y_2(-py_1'-qy_1)=-pw
$$ 
Thus
$$
w(x)=w(x_0)\,\exp\left(\int_{x_0}^x p(s)\,ds\right).
$$
In your case
$$
w(t)=\left|\begin{array}{rr}0 & -1 \\ -1 & 1\end{array}\right|\exp(-x^3/3)=\exp(-x^3/3)
$$

Answer (score 3):

The wroskian is the determinant:
$$\begin{vmatrix} y_1 & y_2 \\ y_1' & y_2'\end{vmatrix}=y_1y_2'-y_2y_1'$$
There's a theorem that states that, if $y_1,y_2$ are solution's of an second order linear homogeneus equation, then they are LI in some interval iff the wronskian does not vanish in that interval, now see what's your wronskian when evaluated at zero.

Comment: This means I have no other way out .

Comment: I must find y1 and y2... Without finding these is it possible to find the wronkians??

Comment: Yes, you have $y_1(0),y_1'(0), y_2(0),y_2'(0)$ so you have the wronskian at zero.